# How to add custom CSS class to required input label?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I would like to add a CSS class to labels which are before my **required** inputs field. I can do it via JavaScript but I would like to do it in CakePHP.

Is there some options to tell CakePHP to do it automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For one `input`, you can simply do this:

```
$this->Form->input('myfield', [
    'label' => [
        'text' => 'My Field', 
        'class' => 'my-label-class'
    ]
]);
```

If you need to add it to all **required** inputs, you could instead create your own `FormHelper`:

```
App::import('Helper', 'Form') ;

class MyFormHelper extends FormHelper {

    protected function _inputLabel($fieldName, $label, $options) {
        // Extract the required option from the $options array.
        $required = $this->_extractOption('required', $options, false)
          || $this->_introspectModel($this->model(), 'validates', $fieldName);

        // If the input is required, first force the array version for $label,
        // then add the custom class.
        if ($required) {
            if (!is_array($label)) {
                $label = array('text' => $label) ;
            }
            $label = $this->addClass($label, 'my-label-class') ;
        }

        // Then simply call the parent function.
        return parent::_inputLabel($fieldName, $label, $options) ;
    }

}
```

And then in your controller:

```
public $helpers = array(
    'Form' => array('className' => 'MyForm')
);
```

See [FormHelper.php](http://api.cakephp.org/2.7/source-class-FormHelper.html#__introspectModel) for informtion about [`_introspectModel`](https://api.cakephp.org/2.7/source-class-FormHelper.html#__introspectModel), basically:

```
$this->_introspectModel ($model, 'validates', $fieldName)
```

...will return `true` if `$fieldName` is a required field in your `Model::validates` array.

Comment: @user1315357 You want to add the class to every labels generated by `FormHelper`?

Comment: @user1315357 Are you using CakePHP 2 or CakePHP 3?

Comment: I use still CakePHP 2.7.3

Comment: @user1315357 See my edit, I don't think there is a shorter way to do what you want in CakePHP 2.

Comment: @Holt you can [change the default template used](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7/lib/Cake/View/Helper/HtmlHelper.php#L89) instead of overriding the helper, [also in the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#changing-the-tags-output-by-htmlhelper).

Comment: @AD7six You're right, I did not know this was possible in CakePHP 2.

Comment: I'll try it later, but I am not sure, does this solution add a CSS class ONLY into labels for required inputs?

Comment: @user1315357 Sorry, I misread your question. See my updated answer.